# Executing chain of commands in Powershell Pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-4.0, runspace

I want to execute a set of powershell commands to manage my HyperV Guest machine.  Can I use the below code to do this ? Do I need to clear pipeline.Commands before executing the next command ?

```
Collection<PSObject> results = null;
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Shutdown-VM ADServer-01");
    results = pipeline.Invoke();
    //Do I need pipeline.Commands.Clear();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-VMState ADServer-01");
    results = pipeline.Invoke();
    runspace.Close();
}
```

Comment: Consider using the `PowerShell` class instead of `Pipeline`. Use `AddStatement()` in between individual pipelines and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you show here, I cannot see a reason for you to use the clear effort.

Comment: I dont need to keep the Shutdown Command in the collection after its invoked right ?